# Reducing Spaces: Evolution

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

Regard a projection:
$$P\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad P^2=P=P^*$$

Then one has:
$$PH\subseteq HP\iff[e^{itH},P]\equiv0$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your notation means that, for every $h \in \mathcal{D}(H)$, one has $Ph \in \mathcal{D}(H)$ and $HPh = PHh$. If that is the case, let $R(\lambda)=(H-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda\not\in\sigma(H)$ and note that
$$
      P(H-\lambda I)h = (H-\lambda I)Ph,\;\;\; h \in \mathcal{D}(H) \\
       R(\lambda)Pg = PR(\lambda)g,\;\;\; g \in \mathcal{H}.
$$
By Stone's theorem, $E(S)P=PE(S)$ for all Borel subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, where $E$ is the spectral measure for $H$. Therefore, using the Borel functional calculus gives $e^{itH}P=Pe^{itH}$.

On the other hand, if $e^{itH}P=Pe^{itH}$, and if $h\in\mathcal{D}(H)$, then $e^{itH}h$ is strongly differentiable in $t$ and, hence, $e^{itH}Ph$ is strongly differentiable in $t$, which gives $Ph \in \mathcal{D}(H)$ and
$$
                 \frac{d}{dt}e^{itH}Ph|_{t=0}= P\frac{d}{dt}e^{itH}h|_{t=0} \\
                             HPh = PHh.
$$

Comment: Besides, I really really love this proof for: $H\to R(\lambda)\to U(t)\to H$